# How to make a union query search using Criteria API

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, search, union, criteria-api

I tried to make a search in db for several fields using input string.

What i've got using HQL.

```
   @Override
    public List<Teacher> searchByString(String str) {

        String[] fields  = {"fam", "name", "otch", "phoneNumber"};
        List<Teacher> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length-1 ; i++) {
            result.addAll(em.createQuery(
                    "SELECT c FROM Teacher c WHERE lower(c." + fields[i] + ") LIKE lower(?1)")
                    .setParameter("1", "%" + str + "%")
                    .getResultList());
        }

        result.addAll(em.createQuery(
                "SELECT c FROM Teacher c WHERE to_char(c." + "dateOfBirth, 'yyyy-mm-dd'" + ") LIKE ?1")
                .setParameter("1", "%" + str + "%")
                .getResultList());

        return result;
    }
```

This example working, but i need to have it in Criteria. I found nothing about "union" in Criteria API. How can i achive this result?

Comment: JPA does not support UNION. But I don't think that you need a union. You could simply create a where clause with all the conditions.

Comment: you mean like select * from teacher where(fam like ? or name like ?)

Comment: yes. Exactly. You could use Predicates see https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-and-or-criteria-predicates

Comment: Once you've implemented the solution it would be great if you could post it as the answer of your question

Comment: Of cource i will